# Is there something about the os module I'm not getting?

Tags: python, syntax, file, operating-system

For the last half hour I've been trying to figure out what is wrong with this code. It should be very straight forward. I've practically copied it out of the documentation at this point. But no matter what I try I receive a syntax error.

Here's the code:

```
def addfiles(folder):
    foldercont = [os.path.normcase(f) for f in os.listdir(folder)]
    for x in foldercont:
        if os.path.isfile(x) == True:
            files.append(os.path.realpath(x)
        if os.path.isdir(x) == True:
            addfiles(os.path.realpath(x))
```

Whenever I run this, i receive the error

```
 if os.path.isdir(x) == True:
                           ^
 SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

However, if I write the equivlent code in the interactive interpreter it runs fine.

Can this method simply not be used in an if loop or something?

Thanks for the help. I'm getting really frustrated at this point... heh.

Comment: why are you using "== True" anyway?

Comment: Make sure you don't have any hidden unicode characters on that line in your editor.

Comment: @jcomeau_jctx It just happend as I kept on rewriting the code to figure out what the problem was.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's a parenthesis missing at this line:

```
files.append(os.path.realpath(x)
                                ^
```

Python complains about the `True:` bit because it's expecting a statement like

```
(x if condition else y)
```

As jcomeau_ictx says, you should also leave out the `== True` when checking for booleans:

```
if x:
    do_something
if not y:
    do_something_else
```

Comment: thanks... I can't believe I've spent all this time missing that. Maybe  I need to get some sleep.

Answer (score 1):

you're missing a close parentheses on the previous line.